# Firestore dynamically build the query

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a query function that dynamically contructs a query - However i can seem to get any of the query elements to bind to the query:

Here I create the observable where I pass the ref to a query building function which adds everything I need searched:

```
firebaseObservable = this.firestoreService.colWithIds$('bucket', ref => this.createFirebaseQuery(ref, this.filterParams.filterBy, pagination));
```

Here I construct the query

```
createFirebaseQuery(ref: any, categories: string[], isPagination?: boolean) {

// Fetch the requests order by direction
const direction: OrderByDirection = this.filterParams.sortBy.direction === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';

// Add th category search criteria
for (const category of categories) {
  ref.where(`categoriesTest.${category}`, '==', 'true');
}


// Order by selected type and direction
ref.orderBy(this.filterParams.sortBy.type, direction);

// Check if the requests skills are new page
if (isPagination) {
  ref.startAfter(this.paginationCursor);
}

// Add a limit to the results being returned
ref.limit(20);



   return ref;
  }
```

This never seems to apply any of the where clauses or Limits to it...?

Answer (score 0):

When applying the where function it returns a Query type, where you can keep adding your filters from it... if you try to get the result from the ref it will ignore your filters.

Instead, you should save the query in a variable and get the results from it

```
const query = ref.where(`fieldName`, '==', 'true');
query.where(`fieldName2`, '==', 'someString');
return await query.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
myFunction(){
    return this.afs.collection<Adocao>('adocao', ref => {
      return ref.where('adotado', '==', false)
      .where('filhote', '==', true)
      .where('porte', '==', 'Médio')
      .where('sexo', '==', 'Fêmea')
      .where('tipo', '==', 'Gato')
    })
    .valueChanges()
}
```